# Two Gamma functions with common terms produces new Gamma and Beta functions

Tags: independence, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

Let X and Y be independent random variables, X ~ Gamma(α,λ) and Y ~ Gamma(β,λ). Prove tha S=X+Y andT =X/(X+Y) are independent ,S~Gamma(α+β,λ) and T ∼Beta(α,β).

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I used moment generating function to prove that X + Y has a Gamma(a+b,lambda). I stuck at how to prove T~Beta(a,b) and their independency.

Comment: Use the Jacobian formula for the joint distribution of $(S,T)$.